# Print Spooler keeps stopping. Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, printer, print-spooler

A Windows XP SP3 PC keeps stopping the Print Spooler job.  This happens for both a normal user and a local admin account.  If we restart the service and try to add a printer, we get an error that the print spooler service is not running.

- There is nothing under c:\windows\system32\spool\printers\ to delete.
- I tried deleting all contents of c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers, but Windows said some files were in use, even when the print spooler was stopped.
- There are no printers showing in Printers & Faxes.
- The system error log shows an error: "The Print Spooler service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 3 time(s)."  Event ID= 7034 & 7031.  This error is repeated 25 times today and yesterday.
- The event immediately prior to these is:
  "The device, \Device\Ide\iaStor0, did not respond within the timeout period." Event Id=9.

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system restore resolved this.